# Using DISTINCT along with GROUP BY in HIVE

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, distinct, hiveql

I'm new to working with Hive, but I am trying to print a table with a total number of car body types for different cities.

```
 select body_type, city, count(body_type) AS total_for_body
 from usedcartestfinal
 group by body_type, city
 order by total_for_body DESC
 LIMIT 20;
```

When I run the above, I get a print out of duplicate cities, and I only want a city to be printed once, I figured I'd use SELECT DISTINCT city, yet I can't as I get an error that Group By cannot be used in the same query.

Not quite sure how else to go about this query, any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmsQa.jpg

I essentially only want Houston to print once since the highest sold there is SUV/CROSSOVER

Comment: Only _printed_ once? Since you group by two columns, each city can be returned several times. If you want each city only once, you have to decide which of its different body_type values to return.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean by that? When I run my query this is what I get, https://imgur.com/BfQVsjF , essentially I only want Houston to print out once, since the most sold their is the SUV. So not quite sure how to go about that

Comment: can you maybe provide a sample scheme of the table `usedcartestfinal`? Which columns does the table have and which datatypes?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `body_type` from the `group by` clause, and instead have a distinct count on it:

```sql
select   city, count(distinct body_type) AS total_for_body 
from     usedcartestfinal 
group by city
order by total_for_body DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery with analytic row_number to get record with highest count for each city:

```
select body_type, city, total_for_body
from
( 
select  body_type, city, total_for_body
        row_number() over(partition by city order by total_for_body desc) rn
from
(
 select body_type, city, count(body_type) total_for_body
 from usedcartestfinal
group by body_type, city
)s
)s where rn = 1
```

Comment: I suspect the data model behind could have been created in a more handable way but this is pretty overwhelming if you justed started SQL. I would have stored the `car_body_types` and the `cities` in different tables and create a third relational table. Then the query would be way easier with a simple join

Answer (score 0):

If you will include the `BODY_TYPE` in the `GROUP BY` then it will be grouped by `BODY_TYPE` and `CITY` so for each `CITY` and each `BODYTYPE`, you will get one row.

You should remove `BODYTYPE` from the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` list as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT BODY_TYPE,
       CITY,
       COUNT(DISTINCT BODY_TYPE) AS TOTAL_FOR_BODY,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CITY 
                          ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT BODY_TYPE) DESC) AS RN
  FROM USEDCARTESTFINAL
 GROUP BY BODY_TYPE,
          CITY) AS T WHERE RN = 1
 ORDER BY TOTAL_FOR_BODY DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I would need to include the body_type to show the number of body_types there are in that city. For example: Houston | Sedan | 500 But I would need to exclude the same city from showing up again, Houston | Coupe | 300.I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: So you want to see only the `car_body_type` with the most sold models per city? Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, I have used the analytical function to order by count and you will find per city only one record in your result.